# append values to drupal7 cck link field entry

Tags: 7, entities, navigation

I've got a question about the CCK link field.

I'm using the link field as a way to get a youtube video embedded onto a page and displayed through colorbox, but in order to make it work I have to include all the embed video information like size and iframe acceptance.

i.e. ?width=560&height=315&iframe=true

Ideally I'd love my users to just have to put the video link in and not worry about including the size specs.

is there any way i can append this kind of information to this field?

I'm using:
D 7.23
CCK link mod 7.x-1.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Media: Youtube module](https://drupal.org/project/media_youtube).

You would then create a file field with a Media file selector widget. Make sure you configure the field to use the Youtube URI schema.

You can configure the size of the video through the field display settings.

When you create a new node, you will need the share url, like http://youtu.be/n1yxNjU7u_8 to embed it.